# Error: Too many re-renders. with useState

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I know this question has been asked by many people, but I tried the method mentioned, but it still didn't work。
Here is my code

```
let tmp:any = {
  "title": "Product Set",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
          "name": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "age": {
            "type": "number"
          },
          "money": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
}


const SForm = () => {

  const { projectId } = useParams() as { projectId: string }
  const [schema , setSchema] = useState(tmp);

  async function getData(id: number) {
    const { data }  = await http.post('/project/testparam', {
    project_id: id,
  })
  
  return data.data
  }
  
 
  setSchema(getData(+projectId))


  return (
        <Form schema = {schema as JSONSchema7}
        >
        </Form>
  )
}
```

Many people say the reason is：everything between the curly braces gets evaluated immediately.
use arrow function.

```
  setSchema(()=> {
    getData(+projectId)
  })
```

But it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the schema on every render. Calling a `setState` hook triggers a render.

What is happening is as follows:

```
intialRender -> setSchema -> re-render -> setSchema -> re-render -> ...
```

You likely want to only get a schema once for a projectId:

```js
const schema = useMemo(() => getData(+projectId), [getData, projectId])
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, which perfectly solves my problem

Comment: @jason-lin Glad to hear! Remember to mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

put the function inside a useEffect function so it runs once at render time

```
useEffect(() => {

  setSchema(getData(+projectId))

}, [/* dependencies */])
```

the dependencies box is to pass params that will run the useEffect everytime that param is re-rendered